# PHP Query: Set parameter to an Sql key for JSON search

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, mysql-json

I have a problem here, my code is:

```
$query = $con2->createQueryBuilder()->select('*')
                ->from('`blog_entry`', 'p')
                ->where('WHERE url->"$.?" = ?')
                ->setParameter(0, $request->getLocale())
                ->setParameter(1, $entryUrl);
```

The url field is a JSON field, and it contains like this:
*{"es": "url.html"}*

But it appears the next error:

**SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens**

I think that the part of **url->"$.?"** is the error, but I don't know how to pass the parameter there, any ideas?

Comment: There is only one `?` token in your query because the first `?` is in quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind to a JSON path like that. From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html):

> Parameter markers can be used only where data values should appear, not for SQL keywords, identifiers, and so forth.

You will need to change your `where()` call to include the path instead, and remove that parameter value:

```
$query = $con2->createQueryBuilder()->select('*')
                ->from('`blog_entry`', 'p')
                ->where('WHERE url->"$.' . $request->getLocale() . '" = ?')
                ->setParameter(0, $entryUrl);
```

**Update**

Inspired by FMK, I've done a bit of testing on my own server, and discovered that this will work:

```
$query = $con2->createQueryBuilder()->select('*')
                ->from('`blog_entry`', 'p')
                ->where('WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(url, ?) = ?')
                ->setParameter(0, '"$.' . $request->getLocale() . '"')
                ->setParameter(1, $entryUrl);
```

Comment: It works! But this can be dangerous? To put directly in SQL without parameters?

Comment: @MarcGarcia yes, it is more dangerous, so you would need to check that the value of `$request->getLocale()` was valid.

Comment: @MarcGarcia I think I've figured out a way around it. See my edit.

Comment: Nope: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
Don't worry, I will use the first part!

Comment: @MarcGarcia it's working on my server (although not using laravel, just the direct mysqli interface), can you post the exact error message you got? I might be able to resolve it. As you say in your first comment, this would be less dangerous. No rush, I'm just curious...

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(url, '\"$.es\"')
MySQL v: Version: 5.7.24

Comment: Looks like you need to change `'"$.' . $request->getLocale() . '"'` to `'$.' . $request->getLocale()`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT('url','$.?') = '?'
```

Comment: Is that for MySql??

Comment: MySQL uses `JSON_EXTRACT`, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html